# Replace string between 2 wildcard characters in a variable value using bash scripting

Tags: bash-scripting

I have a variable value "Cash_20200413_US_02.dat" and I want to rename it as "Cash_20200413_US_*.dat".

So basically I want to find :
a) the last occurence of string "_"
and
b) string "."
and then replace the value between these two strings to "*"

Input="Cash_20200413_US_02.dat"

Output="Cash_20200413_US_*.dat"

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
Input="Cash_20200413_US_02.dat"
```

you can get the substring up to the last underscore (excluded) with:

```
echo "${Input%_*}"
```

and the substring from the last dot (excluded) with:

```
echo "${Input/*.}"
```

Combining both, with the requested string in between:

```
Output="${Input%_*}_*.${Input/*.}"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Your command gave me the desired output.